# Mtcnn face alignment in C++

Tags: c++, opencv, face-detection

I can detecting faces in mtcnn and have the required face points for alignment.

I couldn find a good example how to align faces in mtcnn with c++ ?

How can I align face in opencv , i have location points for eyes , nose and mouth edges ? (coming from mtcnn)

Thanks

Comment: Try first answerfrom OpenCV forum: http://answers.opencv.org/question/24670/how-can-i-align-face-images/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mtcnn uses opencv's warpaffine method to align the faces. What you need is landmark points, transform matrix and the final size of the image you want.

Here is an implementation of face alignment using c++:
https://github.com/deepinsight/insightface/blob/master/cpp-align/FacePreprocess.h

There is another python implementation of it, if you are interested.

Look for the preprocess() function in: https://github.com/deepinsight/insightface/blob/f61956fda322db9977a9bc250031c079c2eb6192/src/common/face_preprocess.py